# Configure HikariDataSource with Mssql properties connectRetryCount and connectRetryInterval

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, hikaricp, mssql-jdbc

I have used HikariCP for connection pooling, so the hikari will try to connection database for around 2min as configure timeout but I also want that connection object given by hikari
also use mssql **ConnectRetryCount** and **ConnectRetryInterval** property so that connection object will also try to connect for serval time if connection is fail.

Please suggest me how can do this or let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

```
HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .driverClassName(driver)
                .url(url)
                .username(user)
                .password(password)
                .type(HikariDataSource.class).build();
        hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(2);
        hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(120000);
        hikariDataSource.setValidationTimeout(120000);
```

```
Driver Name : com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

```
URL : jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1501;DatabaseName=feature57;ConnectRetryCount=4;ConnectRetryInterval=50
```

Comment: What version of the JDBC driver are you using? The `connectRetryCount` and `connectRetryInterval` [connection properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties) require version 9.4 or later.

Comment: it's mssql-jdbc-9.4.0.jre11.jar - @AlwaysLearning